# Should this question be marked as spam?

Tags: discussion, flags, specific-question, spam

I came across this post on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13207957/ssis-common-transformations-video-tutorial:

[image: SO question]

It is not a question because it is an advertisement even though the video links might be useful to users following the tag [ssis](/questions/tagged/ssis). I am posting this question here on Meta because I was in dilemma whether to flag it as `spam` or vote to `close`. Flag as spam has the following description.

> This question is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.

However, I think that the post has a disclosure from the authors. I assume that disclosure means just displaying your name in the post. I could be wrong. It might be helpful but it is still promotional, in my point of view.

Should this post have been marked as spam?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The disclosure requirement is for answers, and it only applies when the somewhat promotional answer actually answers the question. Disclosure doesn't allow you to post promotional content anywhere you like.

This is spam, it is purely promotional. So I think flagging as spam is justified.

Comment: Shouldnt it be deleted rather than closing it ?

Comment: @2-Stroker Flagging as spam deletes the post if 6 users or one mod flag it as such

Comment: Since you are a moderator on two SE sites, I trust your response. Thanks for clarifying that. @2-Stroker: That was my dilemma, if I had flagged it as spam, it would have been deleted by a moderator.

Comment: @Siva: Eventually, it was deleted anyway.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha: Yes, I believe that's because of too many downvotes generated from users who read this MSO post. I have seen questions lingering in [tag:SSIS] for long time even after I voted for close. Sometimes I had to flag them for moderators attention.